# Cookie not writing (Nest.js on Railway.app and Remix on Netlify)

Tags: cookies

I'm using a nest.js backend deployed to Railway.app and a Remix front end deployed to Netlify.  It is a cookie authentication system, working fine on localhost.  When I log in, the nest app returns a graphql query with Headers that should write a cookie - I've tried tons of variations based on other posts but none have worked, so I'm hoping a very specific ask can help me find the answer.

The API is on api-beta.biztobiznow.com and the site is on beta.biztobiznow.com. These are the headers I'm seeing after login on beta.biztobiznow.com

__session=xxxx; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None

Both sites are secure, but after the request, there is no _session cookie available on beta.

I've tried it with the domain set to 'biztobiznow.com' and '.biztobiznow.com'

Does anyone have insight on what might get this cookie written by the browser?

Not sure if this helps, here is the entire Headers received on the login page.

```
Request URL:
https://beta-api.biztobiznow.com/graphql
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200
Remote Address:
104.196.232.237:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
https://beta.biztobiznow.com
Cache-Control:
no-store
Content-Length:
667
Content-Type:
application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:
Tue, 15 Aug 2023 19:55:50 GMT
Etag:
W/"29b-G/+ln/HW0BHemKDz+8xgCQWFvS8"
Server:
railway
Set-Cookie:
__session=xxx; Domain=.biztobiznow.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
Vary:
Origin
X-Powered-By:
Express
:authority:
beta-api.biztobiznow.com
:method:
POST
:path:
/graphql
:scheme:
https
Accept:
*/*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
en,es;q=0.9
Authorization:
Bearer
Content-Length:
884
Content-Type:
application/json
Origin:
https://beta.biztobiznow.com
Referer:
https://beta.biztobiznow.com/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?1
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Android"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
same-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
```